# Submit from with ajax with php script, html and JavaScript on same php document

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Am new to ajax and I am trying to submit a form input to database and retrieve data form database. The thing is that i have JS, PHP, HTML on the same document.

**user_msg.php**

```
<body style="background-color: #eee">
<div class='head_msg'></div>
<div class="msg_user_area">
<br><br><br>
<?php
    echo "Your conversations";

    $my_id = $_SESSION['log_id'];

    $gsql = <<<EOF
SELECT hash, user_one, user_two FROM connect WHERE user_one = '$my_id' OR user_two = '$my_id';
EOF;
    $gret = $db->query($gsql);

    while ($grow = $gret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        $hash = $grow['hash'];
        $user_one = $grow['user_one'];
        $user_two = $grow['user_two'];

        if ($user_one == $my_id) {
            $select_id = $user_two;
        } else {
            $select_id = $user_one;
        }

        $sesql = <<<EOF
SELECT * FROM User WHERE ID = '$select_id';
EOF;
        $seret = $db->query($sesql);

        while ($serow = $seret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
            $select_uname = $serow['fname'];

            echo "<a href='user_msg.php?hash=$hash'><div class='text'>$select_uname</div></a>
        }
}
?>

</div>
<div class='padder'>
<div class='msg_area'>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash']))
{
$hash = $_GET['hash'];
$us_id = $_SESSION['log_id'];

$mesql =<<<EOF
SELECT from_id, message FROM messager WHERE group_hash = '$hash';
EOF;
$meret = $db->query($mesql);
while ($merow = $meret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
    $from_id = $merow['from_id'];
    $messages = $merow['message'];


    $usql =<<<EOF
SELECT * FROM User WHERE ID = '$from_id';
EOF;
    $uret = $db->query($usql);

    while ($urow = $uret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
    {
        $from_fname = $urow['fname'];
        $from_img = $urow['image'];


        if ($from_id != $_SESSION['log_id'])
        {

        echo "
<div class='from_bubble'><div class='from_img'><img src='$from_img'></div><div class='from_txt'><p>$messages</p></div></div>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "
<div class='rep_bubble'><div class='rep_img'><img src='$from_img'></div><div     class='rep_txt'><p>$messages</p></div></div>";
        }
    }

}
if (isset($_POST['rep_msg']) && !empty($_POST['rep_msg']))
{
    $rep_msg = $_POST['rep_msg'];
    $rsql =<<<EOF
INSERT INTO messager (message, group_hash, from_id) VALUES('$rep_msg', '$hash', '$my_id');
EOF;
    $rret = $db->exec($rsql);

    $ursql =<<<EOF
SELECT * FROM User WHERE ID = '$my_id';
EOF;
    $urret = $db->query($ursql);

    while ($urrow = $urret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
    {
        $from_fname = $urrow['fname'];
        $from_img = $urrow['image'];

    header('Location: user_msg.php?hash='.$hash);
}

}

}
?>
</div>
<div class="rep_area">
    <form action="" id="send_rep" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="textarea"><textarea name="rep_msg" placeholder="Message here"></textarea></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function (){
    var msg_area = $('.msg_area');
    msg_area.scrollTop(msg_area.prop("scrollHeight"));

    //Tried this but didn't work 
        $('#send_rep').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'user_msg.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'html'
            })
                .done(function (data) {
                    $('.from_bubble').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
                });
        });
});
</script>
```

This is a chat room. So i ask is it possible to do that is in the php with ajax still with the php code on the same page. That is do all the submit and retrieving of data from database without refreshing the page?

Comment: If you put the PHP API and the JavaScript AJAX call into separate files, then you would find this problem a lot easier to solve. The PHP API should return a result in JSON. The JavaScript AJAX call should query the PHP script for the info, then parse the JSON response as needed.

Comment: Yea I know that would work. But am trying to avoid re-writing the code because i had written it before i leant AJAX. That's why i asked if it was possible.